# copy files from multiple sub-directories to the same destination directory

Tags: cp, file-copy

I have something a directory like this

```
Main Directory
     SubDirectory
        SubsubDirectory1
           xx.jpg
           xx,jpg
        SubsubDirectory2
           xx.jpg
           xx,jpg
     SubDirectory
        SubsubDirectory1
           xx.jpg
           xx,jpg
        SubsubDirectory2
           xx.jpg
           xx,jpg
     SubDirectory
        SubsubDirectory1
           xx.jpg
           xx,jpg
        SubsubDirectory2
           xx.jpg
           xx,jpg
```

I want to copy all files in all SubsubDirectory1 to a destination directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the files have non-unique names, then

```
cp "Main Directory"/*/Subsubdirectory1/* destdir
```

would overwrite some of the files at the destination.  This would also fail if there are *thousands* of matching pathnames.

To get around this, using GNU `cp`:

```
for pathname in "Main Directory"/*/Subsubdirectory1/*; do
    cp --backup=numbered "$pathname" destdir
done
```

This would create numbered backups of the files that would otherwise have been overwritten.

The same thing but using non-GNU `cp`:

```
for pathname in "Main Directory"/*/Subsubdirectory1/*; do

    # create first stab at destination pathname
    dest="destdir/${pathname##*/}"

    i=0
    while [ -e "$dest" ]; do
        # destination name exists, remove backup number from end of
        # pathname and replace with next one in the sequence
        i=$(( i + 1 ))
        dest="${dest%.~*~}.~$i~"
    done

    cp "$pathname" "$dest"
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the files have unique names, so I will try the first solution, and tell you if it works

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`cp  mainDir/*/SubsubDirectory1/* <destination_path>`

Note: file names must be different.

Comment: I will give it a try and give you feedback